# Buffer Not Large enough for pixel

Tags: kotlin, bitmap, buffer

I am trying to get a bitmap From byte array

```
                            val bitmap_tmp =
                                Bitmap.createBitmap(height, width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                            val buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(decryptedText)
                            bitmap_tmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)
                            callback.bitmap(bitmap_tmp)
```

I am facing a error in the below line :

```
                            bitmap_tmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)
```

The Error Reads As:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels
```

I have tried Different Solutions found on stack Like Add the line before error but still it crashes:

```
buffer.rewind()
```

However the Weird part is the same code at a different place for the same image [Same image with same dimensions] get perfectly functioned and I get the bitmap but here it crashes.
How do I solve this?
Thanks in Adv

Answer (score 0):

The error message makes it sound like the buffer you're copying from isn't large enough, like it needs to contain *at least as many bytes* as necessary to overwrite every pixel in your bitmap (which has a set size and pixel config).

The documentation for the method doesn't make it clear, but [here's the source for the Bitmap class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/7f9f99ea11051614a7727dfb9f9578b518e76e3c/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#364), and in that method:

```
if (bufferBytes < bitmapBytes) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Buffer not large enough for pixels");
}
```

So yeah, you can't partially overwrite the bitmap, you need enough data to fill it. And if you check the source, that depends on the buffer's current `position` and `limit` (it's not just its capacity, it's how much data is remaining to be read).

If it works elsewhere, I'm guessing `decryptedText` is different there, or maybe you're creating your `Bitmap` with a different `Bitmap.Config` (like `ARGB_8888` requires 4 bytes per pixel)